# commandLinkButton in pyqt4

Tags: pyqt4

Following is a part of my code

```
QObject.connect( self.UI.commandLinkButton, SIGNAL("clicked()") ,self.displayShow() )
```

Ideally it should call the displayShow() function on clicking the commandLinkButton but it is calling the function even without clicking the button.

What could be the possible reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
QObject.connect( self.UI.commandLinkButton, SIGNAL("clicked()") ,self.displayShow)
```

Note: no `()` after the function name.